# How to validate model manually in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I think that `Controller.ValidateModel` does not work in MVC 6 to validate a model manually. What's the alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this method was just added on Jan/13/2015. So it's currently available in the dev builds, and will become public with Beta3.